# How to recover the title of an <a>

Tags: javascript, tags

it's my first question on this site.
I have something like this :

```
<a href="project/150" title="FR - This is an example" target="_blank">FR - This is an example"
```

And i'm looking for something that would catch the "FR" in the beginning of my title in javascript. I don't really know if it's possible and I'm kinda bad in javascript so i appreciate your help :)

EDIT !

I'm maybe not enough specific, and I'm sorry for this. I'm modifying an existant software. I have something like this in my HTML inspector :

```
<div class="nameoftheclass">
:: before
<a href="project/150" title="FR - This is an example" target="_blank">FR - This is an example</a>
::after
</div>
```

I want to add the FR that I found in my "a" to my class in my "div". I will have to do this for 15 tags after this one, so I cannot just write FR. I hope those explanations will give you more informations that could help

Comment: Catch when / in response to what? Do what with it afterwards?

Comment: To stock it in an array

Comment: You'd need a way to identify that particular link element in your page *(`id`, `className`, "3rd `<a>` in the 2nd `<p>` of the `<section>` after ...")*. And then basically `thatParticularLinkElement.title.substring(0,2)`. Can't get more precise with so little to work with.

Comment: Could the "FR" string be dynamic? "EN" in another example? and will "-" always be your separator?

Comment: Let's try it differently. If I look at the entire markup of your entire page *(this is most likely not the only link in there)* how would/could I know/determine which link you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the elements with the tag a by

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

It returns a HTMLCollection of all elements with the tag a.

Now we can loop over it and check if there is an element which has a title starts with `'FR'` using Strings `startsWith()` method.

```js
let allA = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
let found = false;
for(let l = 0; l < allA.length; l++){
  if (allA[l].title.startsWith('FR')) {
    found = true
  }
}

console.log(found);
```

```html
<a href="project/150" title="FR - This is an example" target="_blank">FR - This is an example"</a>
```

Comment: I just tried it, but it returns me a false

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle? As you can see in the snippet above it returns true

Comment: @AlexBrianceau is that your very first link in that page? If not, try a different index than `0`.

Comment: Also in your shared code `<a href="project/150" title="FR - This is an example" target="_blank">FR - This is an example"` you haven't closed your tag.
Add at the end `</a>` and yes as @Thomas said this code works at the moment just for your first tag.
You can consider giving your <a> element an id and use the selector `document.getElementById()`  then you can also get rid of `[0]`

Comment: It's not the first tag so yes, the [0] did not work. It doesn't have an id, so can't I getElementByTitle or something like this ?

Comment: you can get all elements with a tag as above loop over them and check which of them starts with fr

Comment: @AlexBrianceau I would recommend updating your question with this details to make it more clear otherwise its likely that the question will be closed

Comment: Thank you ! It works, have a very nice day, you made mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but you should adapt it if your element is in a loop. this will get dynamically the "Lang" value:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
var title = element.title.split('-');
console.log(title[0]);
```

make sure you add a class or an Id to your element.